# Error in adding platform to cordova project

Tags: cordova

I am trying to add android platform to my cordova project. i have added path variable of both android sdk platform tools and tools. My JDK and ant run correctly. but when i try to execute this command

c:\cordova\hello\cordova platform add android

I got these errors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.3.tgz

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.3.tgz

what can i do?

Comment: Is that all you got ? Can we have the whole output ?

Comment: do you have node.js installed? It's better to install cordova CLI by using npm.

Comment: error seems incomplete

Comment: My node.js and cordova are running properly. I have installed cordova CLI by using npm. But whenever i try to add the platform every single time i got the above two error.